# How to groupBy on two columns and work out avg total value for each grouped column using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame and using Pyspark, I'm trying to get the following answers:

1. Total Fare by Pick
2. Total Tip by Pick
3. Avg Drag by Pick
4. Avg Drag by Drop

| Pick | Drop | Fare | Tip | Drag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4.00 | 4.00 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 2 | 5.00 | 10.00 | 8.00 |
| 1 | 2 | 5.00 | 15.00 | 12.00 |
| 3 | 2 | 11.00 | 12.00 | 17.00 |
| 3 | 5 | 41.00 | 25.00 | 13.00 |
| 4 | 6 | 50.00 | 70.00 | 2.00 |

My Query is so far like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc

data = [
    (1, 1, 4.00, 4.00, 1.00),
    (1, 2, 5.00, 10.00, 8.00),
    (1, 2, 5.00, 15.00, 12.00),
    (3, 2, 11.00, 12.00, 17.00),
    (3, 5, 41.00, 25.00, 13.00),
    (4, 6, 50.00, 70.00, 2.00)
]

columns = ["Pick", "Drop", "Fare", "Tip", "Drag"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)


df.groupBy('Pick', 'Drop') \
    .agg(
        func.sum('Fare').alias('FarePick'),
        func.sum('Tip').alias('TipPick'),
        func.avg('Drag').alias('AvgDragPick'),
        func.avg('Drag').alias('AvgDragDrop')) \
    .orderBy('Pick').show()
```

However, I don't think it seems to be correct. I'm abit stuck on (4) because the groupby does not seem correct. Can anyone suggest correction here. The output needs to be in One (1) table together such as:

| Pick | Drop | FarePick | TipPick | AvgDragPick | AvgDragDrop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order you want to have all columns in it just use Window functions.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [
    (1, 1, 4.00, 4.00, 1.00),
    (1, 2, 5.00, 10.00, 8.00),
    (1, 2, 5.00, 15.00, 12.00),
    (3, 2, 11.00, 12.00, 17.00),
    (3, 5, 41.00, 25.00, 13.00),
    (4, 6, 50.00, 70.00, 2.00)
]

columns = ["Pick", "Drop", "Fare", "Tip", "Drag"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df_new = (
    df
    .withColumn("TotalFarePick", f.sum("Fare").over(Window.partitionBy("Pick")))
    .withColumn("TotalTipPick", f.sum("Tip").over(Window.partitionBy("Pick")))
    .withColumn("AvgDragPick", f.avg("Drag").over(Window.partitionBy("Pick")))
    .withColumn("AvgDragDrop", f.avg("Drag").over(Window.partitionBy("Drop")))
    .drop("Fare", "Tip", "Drag")
)

df_new.show()
```

Also please do not use `\` as they should not be used in newer python versions.

See for that https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/ :

**The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python’s implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.**

Answer (score 0):

I added your table data into a `data` variable, and separated the 4 step.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("testSession") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [
    (1, 1, 4.00, 4.00, 1.00),
    (1, 2, 5.00, 10.00, 8.00),
    (1, 2, 5.00, 15.00, 12.00),
    (3, 2, 11.00, 12.00, 17.00),
    (3, 5, 41.00, 25.00, 13.00),
    (4, 6, 50.00, 70.00, 2.00)
]

columns = ["Pick", "Drop", "Fare", "Tip", "Drag"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# 1 and 2 and 3
df.groupBy('Pick').agg(
    func.sum('Fare').alias('TotalFarePick'),
    func.sum('Tip').alias('TotalTipPick'),
    func.avg('Drag').alias('AvgDragPick')
).orderBy('Pick').show()

# 4
df.groupBy('Drop').agg(
    func.avg('Drag').alias('AvgDragDrop')
).orderBy('Drop').show()

spark.stop()
```

The output of the two tables:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+
|Pick|TotalFarePick|TotalTipPick|AvgDragPick|
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+
|   1|         14.0|        29.0|        7.0|
|   3|         52.0|        37.0|       15.0|
|   4|         50.0|        70.0|        2.0|
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+

+----+------------------+
|Drop|       AvgDragDrop|
+----+------------------+
|   1|               1.0|
|   2|12.333333333333334|
|   5|              13.0|
|   6|               2.0|
+----+------------------+
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thank you, however the output needs to be one table and not two. Is there a way I can do that? (I've updated the question to reflect that)

Comment: you need both pick and drop columns also? I can make it through with join, but without the drop column :-? dunno how should I put both together. is it okay to have null values?

Comment: Yes both columns, I guess they can have nulls, idk... can't seem to think how to join them